# Relation Filtering

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm stuck on how to do this relation.

I have two mySQL models. One named 'Vehicles' and another named 'Checklist'. Evidently, Checklist contains a list of questions and a date field that is automatically generated.

I am making a reporting page, where I'm trying to list each vehicle vertically and then have 12 checkbox widgets horizontally across from each vehicle with a month label above.

I'm trying to get the checkbox's to only be to ticked if a checklist exists with the corresponding date field.

i.e.

```
> Vehicles -- January - February - March - April - May ...  
> Vehicle A -   []    -    []    -  []   -  []   - [] ...
> Vehicle B -   []    -    []    -  []   -  []   - [] ...
> Vehicle C -   []    -    []    -  []   -  []   - [] ...
```

I've read the relations reference but I've hit a wall, not sure how to get this working.

Can somebody put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the value attribute of each checkbox widget, enter this code:

```
(@datasource.item.Checklist..Date || []).some(d => d.getMonth() === #)
```

Where Date is the name of the date field in the checklist table and change the # to the corresponding month of the checkbox (January = 0, February = 1, etc).

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to check other aspects of the Checklist record, you could do something like this:

```
(@datasource.item.Checklist || []).some(c => c.Date.getMonth() === # && c.Status === 'Approved')
```

Comment: One additional question -- each checklist has a status field. I would only like it to return true and tick the box if the checklist's status is 'Approved'. Using your code, the status of the first item determines whether they show true. i.e. If item 0 has "New" Status, none of the later checklists will appear even if they are "Approved". 

How would I go about this? I'm trying to understand your code so I can edit accordingly. I've tried variations of: 

(@datasource.items..Date || []).some(d => d.getMonth() === 3) && @datasource.items..Status === 'Approved'

Comment: @EliasW I updated my answer with the additional requirement

Comment: Thanks. The code I ended up using is: (@datasource.items || []).some(c => c.Date.getMonth() === 0 && c.Status === 'Approved'). You're awesome!